# Raspberry Pi 2B External HDD not detected

Tags: pi-2, usb, hard-drive, usb-hub

I'm trying to connect my external hard drive to my Raspberry Pi 2B, but I am not able to get it to show up. I am running the latest Raspbian, and I have updated my software. Running `lsblk --fs`, I only see the SD card.

```
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot   4467-8C16                             197.6M    22% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs 66f68227-b1ae-4493-9ef5-e593576a6e81    5.7G    55% /
```

I have been getting the following error in `dmesg`

```
[  890.258022] usb 1-1.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[  890.378027] usb 1-1.2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  890.618012] usb 1-1.2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  890.858010] usb 1-1.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using dwc_otg
[  890.978015] usb 1-1.2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  891.218025] usb 1-1.2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  891.338284] usb 1-1.2-port1: attempt power cycle
[  892.038016] usb 1-1.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
[  892.478065] usb 1-1.2.1: device not accepting address 13, error -32
[  892.598031] usb 1-1.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using dwc_otg
[  893.038042] usb 1-1.2.1: device not accepting address 14, error -32
[  893.038368] usb 1-1.2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I initially thought it was a power issue from the Raspberry Pi, so I connected it to an external powered USB hub but I am still seeing the same issue. I have confirmed that the drive works through the hub on my PC.

I also tried setting `max_usb_current=1` in my `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting, but no luck with that either. I am using [this hard drive enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YBAT9Y8) and [this powered USB hub](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07X91YGG1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: what hard drive do you have in the enclosure?

Comment: what's the output of `lsusb`

Comment: It seems that many things from Amazon have issues these days. There have been reports that Amazon no longer exercises any quality control over their vendors. I would send it back to them for a refund.

Comment: @JaromandaX, this is the lsusb output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The hub shows up but the drive doesn't. The hard drive is just a 1TB 2.5" drive from Toshiba

Comment: I can't read that ... perhaps you should put that in the question to make it readable